# do need to use mutex lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Simple edition: In a C++ program I'm using two different threads to work with some integer variable. but I'm sure one is always writing some value into it and the other one is only reading That. do I still need to use mutex lock when reading/writing data?

Now details : The main idea is that first thread generates some information and saves them into an array, and the second thread reads data from that array and process them. this array represents a queue. meaning I have two index values pointing to the first and last item in queue. Now I'm wondering if I have to lock these two index values whenever I'm reading or writing values or is it ok to check them without locking? note that generator thread is the only thread changing index of queue_back, and processor thread has exclusive permission to change queue_front.

if makes any change I'm developing for a linux based system and the code is compiled using gcc.

PS: In some codes which use threading, I've seen keyword `volatile` around variables shared between different threads, do I need to use that too?

Comment: If `volatile` is not used, other threads may or may not _ever_ see changes made to the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the read and write are not atomic, You will need to synchronize it using some synchronization mechanism.

Also, You MUST mark the shared integer as volatile, otherwise the optimizer might think the variable is never updated in one of your threads.

`gcc` allows you to do atomic operations on int‘s, long‘s and long long‘s (and their unsigned counterparts).

Look up for the functions:

```
type __sync_fetch_and_add (type *ptr, type value);
type __sync_fetch_and_sub (type *ptr, type value);
type __sync_fetch_and_or (type *ptr, type value);
type __sync_fetch_and_and (type *ptr, type value);
type __sync_fetch_and_xor (type *ptr, type value);
type __sync_fetch_and_nand (type *ptr, type value);
```

Comment: Just about to type in something similar.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Agreed & Modified.

Comment: [`volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) (nor useful, except with a few compilers that add their own definition to get it to do something useful for things like this).

Comment: Reads and writes of an `int` may be atomic in the sense that no thread can read a partially-written value. It depends on the CPU architecture, the size of `int` in octets, whether the `int` object is aligned, and to what boundary it is aligned (e.g. 4 byte, 8 byte, 16 byte, ...).

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: I would not want to rely on the *maybe* when I am writing my code atleast.

Comment: @Als: Yes, I agree. For the most portability, synchronization primitives should be used.

Comment: Can you name architectures that actually have non-atomic load or store? FYI FIFO indices do not need atomic read-modify-write instructions. If you use machine words, i.e. "int" in C, you're hence guaranteed to have an atomic writes and reads. Volatility is correct, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I still need to use mutex lock when reading/writing data?

Yes, you will need a lock. You may be interested in a more specific implementation called a read/write lock.

You can also use atomics and/or memory barriers. Using these will require a better understanding of your target architectures. Reproducing multithreading bugs can be very difficult, and these alternatives should be considered an optimization which may not be portable.

> I've seen keyword volatile around variables shared between different threads, do I need to use that too?

Yikes. No! That is not a safe or portable solution to multithreaded reads and writes in C++. Use atomics, locks, copying, immutable and pure implementations (etc...) instead.

Interpretation of `volatile` can vary by platform and/or compiler, and it's not specified to operate any particular way in C or C++ for the purpose of multithreaded reads and writes (there's an old false legend that it can be used reliably as an atomic read/write). I once tested the effectiveness of `volatile` in a multithreaded C++ program for fun (on an intel-mac with apple's gcc). I won't provide the results because it worked *well enough* that some people might consider using it, although they *should* not because 'almost' isn't good enough.

And to qualify the use of `volatile`: It exists in my (large, strictly written, multithreading aware) codebase for the sole purpose of interfacing with platform dependent atomics APIs. And being entirely honest: there are a few other uses from earlier days, but they can and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to synchronize access to the variable, either with a mutex, a critical section, interlocked access, etc to make sure that the reading thread does not read incomplete bytes while the writing thread is still saving them.  This is especially important on multi-core/CPU systems, where the two threads can truely access the variable in parallel.

Comment: what if limit size of array to 256, and limit index values to a single byte data?

Answer (score 1):

Reads and writes of properly aligned data no larger than a machine word (usually whatever `int` resolves to) are atomic on most major architectures. That does *not* mean *every* architecture.

This means that no, you cannot just read `head` and `tail` and expect that data is consistent. However, if for example `sizeof(int)` happens to be 4 and `sizeof(short)` happens to be 2, and if you don't care about "not mainstream" platforms, you can do some union trickery and get away without atomic operations or a mutex.

If you want your code to be portable, there is no way around proper locking or atomic compare/exchange.

About `volatile`, this *does* insert a memory barrier for Microsoft Visual C++ (as a compiler-specific sophistry) but the standard does *not* guarantee anything special other than that the compiler won't optimize the variable. Insofar, making something `volatile` does not really help much, and it guarantees thread safety in no way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to protect the queue indexes in both the generator and the reader threads by using some kind of synchronization mechanism, like a mutex.

HTH

Comment: Wait, really?  The compiler is not allowed to optimize it away?  I don't think that's right.  That's the only usage of the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @Mooing Duck -- yes, you're right and I was wrong. I changed the answer. Thanks for picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just sharing one single integer, then `std::atomic<int>` sounds like the right type to use, from the `<atomic>` header. (There should also be Boost or TR1 versions if you have an old compiler.) This ensures atomic reads and writes. There's no need for a `volatile` qualifier as far as I understand.

Comment: well it's more than just one integer that I'm sharing but only one integer may be accessed at same time. I mean whole queue variable is shared but both threads first check head and tail variables before trying to access queue nodes.